# List to List of tuples RGB python

Tags: python-3.x, list, rgb

I have a list like this

```
[255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255]
```

What is a best way to convert to pair of 3 (rgb), inside is tuple

```
pixel = [(255,0,0),(255,0,0),(255,0,0),(255,0,0),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use the **iter()** as below:

```
RGB = [255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255]
it = iter(RGB)
print(list(zip(it,it,it)))
```

if you want a group of N elements in tuple you can simply use the zip(it * N) and you will get the N number of elements in a tuple.

Comment: do you know which way is faster? using the for loop or iter

Comment: because my list will be super long

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` is very easy in this case:

```
import numpy as np
pixels = [255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255]
np_pixels = np.array(pixels).reshape((-1, 3))
print(np_pixels)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(np_pixels)
[[255   0   0]
 [255   0   0]
 [255   0   0]
 [255   0   0]
 [127   0 255]
 [127   0 255]
 [127   0 255]
 [127   0 255]
 [127   0 255]
 [  0 127 255]
 [  0 127 255]
 [  0 127 255]
 [  0 127 255]
 [  0 127 255]
 [  0 127 255]
 [  0 127 255]]
```

If you insist on making them tuples you can just do this afterwards:

```
np_pixels = [tuple(row) for row in np_pixels]
```

Output:

```
[(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (127, 0, 255), (127, 0, 255), (127, 0, 255), (127, 0, 255), (127, 0, 255), (0, 127, 255), (0, 127, 255), (0, 127, 255), (0, 127, 255), (0, 127, 255), (0, 127, 255), (0, 127, 255)]
```